The problem with FileProvider (Android Studio)
There is a small code that raises the http server, which in turn listens to the url request for a file name, and then runs it through a standard player, this implementation is necessary for an interesting idea with VR.
But there is a problem! For some reason, FileProvider generates the following path: dat=content://com.example.vrtestvr.fileprovider/external_files/VRvideo/1.mp4, respectively, the player says that the video cannot be buffered and started, with the error code 2005, why is that? It's also funny that it seemed to work, but then it just stopped 0_0. I do not know what to do, tell me friends.
Code MainActivity:
'private void playVideo(File videoFile) {
    if (!videoFile.exists()) {
        Log.e("VideoFileCheck", "File does not exist: " + videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        return;
    }

    String mimeType;
    String extension = videoFile.getName().substring(videoFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();
    switch (extension) {
        case "mp4":
            mimeType = "video/mp4";
            break;
        case "mkv":
            mimeType = "video/x-matroska";
            break;
        default:
            mimeType = "video/*"; 
            break;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", videoFile);
    Log.d("VideoFileCheck", "Video URI: " + videoUri.toString());
    intent.setDataAndType(videoUri, mimeType);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No application found to play video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}'


Link to MainActivity.java: https://pastebin.com/4QSD8TzA
Link to AndroidManifest.xml: https://pastebin.com/Wj64BQcj
Link to FilePaths.xml: https://pastebin.com/daqVxR3p

I tried:

I tried to change something in the provider in the manifest
Tried to fix the code
Tried to play with file_paths.xml and all unsuccessfully

Decision:
I used parse with direct file:///, below I will show the working code:
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); //Required for Android 8+
        Uri data = Uri.parse(new File("file://" + videoFile).toString());
        intent.setDataAndType(data, mimeType);
        startActivity(intent);

Bottom line: the normal way to perform (file:/storage/emulated/0/VRvideo/0.mp4)

please include relevant code in the question itself (preferably a [mre]) - external links can be blocked, changed, and even deleted

Use Uri.FromFile() instead of FileProvider
Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(videoFile);


Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "video/*");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);

When you create the content:// URI, you need to grant the necessary permissions to the video player. This can be done using Intent flags.

I did this, and unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Found a solution, supplemented at the base
